# How to select specific columns in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, orm, eloquent

lets say I have 7 columns in table, and I want to select only two of them, something like this

```
SELECT `name`,`surname` FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '1';
```

In laravel eloquent model it may looks like this

```
Table::where('id', 1)->get();
```

but I guess this expression will select ALL columns where id equals 1, and I want only two columns(name, surname). how to select only two columns?

Comment: Thanks for asking the question.  It's crazy as I've always done this properly in 'classic' SQL queries, but having to use Eloquent, I found it so confusing I was happy just to get it working, and was oblivious to how much memory my queries were using because I was selecting everything.

Comment: ModelName::findOrFail(1, ['name', 'surname']);

Answer (score 402, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Table::select('name','surname')->where('id', 1)->get();
```

Comment: let's suppose i want to select every field expect one how can i do that

Comment: First of all, when you have question, ask one. And for your case - just mention all columns instead of the one you don't want to include. It's that easy.

Comment: isn't there  any other method for doing that without mentioning all columns

Comment: This works for a basic case with a single table. However, if you are using a relation over a pivot table, then this will ALSO select the pivot columns, automatically.

Comment: Does it format SQL with this fields, or it filters output data?

Comment: @OPV It just runs `SELECT name, surname FROM Table where id = 1` SQL query

Comment: I see you applied the get method at the end which runs the query on the query builder instance, I'm wondering does this return a collection of say the User objects (the active record way) or just an array containing the results from the underlying SQL query?

Comment: How to get field twice with alias?

Comment: came here just to check if I was thinking right about not needing to `select(['field1','field2'])` this way without the array is cleaner and better hehe. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek, may I ask you to have a look at a Laravel search related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76485513/laravel-search-with-multiple-keywords-against-multiple-columns-with-the-search ?

Comment: @PrinceArora You can do this, but I doubt it's very efficient.

$columns = array_filter(\Schema::getColumnListing($model->getTable()), function ($column) {
    return $column != 'exclude_column';
});
    $model->select($columns)->where('id', 1)->get();

Answer (score 136):

```
Table::where('id', 1)->get(['name','surname']);
```

Comment: I want the same thing but using different method. I want to select method by creating instance of model and then select column. i.e $model = new MyModel(); $model->select(['col1', 'col2']); But this thing is not working

Comment: I believe this is the way it is supposed to be used. I don't know if select() is faster than get() though.

Comment: can also be `model::where('col', val)->get(['col1', 'col2']);`

Answer (score 101):

You can also use `find()` like this:

```
ModelName::find($id, ['name', 'surname']);
```

The `$id` variable can be an array in case you need to retrieve multiple instances of the model.

Answer (score 92):

By using all() method we can select particular columns from table like as shown below.

```
ModelName::all('column1', 'column2', 'column3');
```

**Note**: Laravel 5.4

Comment: I want the same thing but using different method. I want to select method by creating instance of model and then select column. i.e $model = new MyModel(); $model->select(['col1', 'col2']); But this thing is not working.

Answer (score 50):

You first need to create a Model, that represent that Table and then use the below Eloquent way to fetch the data of only 2 fields.

```
Model::where('id', 1)
         ->pluck('name', 'surname')
         ->all();
```

Comment: This is the best answer since it works also with pivot tables in many to many relationships.

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: Remember that the order when using pluck with two parameters is column, key - so the second item will be the array key and the first it's corresponding value.

Comment: This is the most suitable solution.

Answer (score 32):

Also `Model::all(['id'])->toArray()` it will only fetch id as array.

Answer (score 27):

Get the value of one column:

```
Table_Name::find($id)->column_name;
```

you can use this method with a where clause:

```
Table_Name::where('id',$id)->first()->column_name;
```

or use this method to bypass PhpStorm "Method where not found in App\Models":

```
Table_Name::query()->where('id','=',$id)->first()->column_name;
```

in query builder:

```
DB::table('table_names')->find($id)->column_name;
```

with where clause:

```
DB::table('table_names')->where('id',$id)->first()->column_name;
```

or

```
DB::table('table_names')->where('id',$id)->first('column_name');
```

last method result is an array

Comment: Important to mention that only the last query actually does what you want and only requests the id from the DB with `SELECT id FROM...`, rather just  `SELECT * FROM...` which selects all columns of the table. There is a performance difference, so important to consider.

Answer (score 18):

You can use get() as well as all()

```
ModelName::where('a', 1)->get(['column1','column2']);
```

Comment: This answer should have much more votes.

Answer (score 12):

From laravel 5.3 only using `get()` method you can get specific columns of your table:

```
YouModelName::get(['id', 'name']);
```

Or from laravel 5.4 you can also use `all()` method for getting the fields of your choice:

```
YourModelName::all('id', 'name');
```

with both of above method `get()` or `all()` you can also use `where()` but syntax is different for both:

**Model::all()**

```
YourModelName::all('id', 'name')->where('id',1);
```

**Model::get()**

```
YourModelName::where('id',1)->get(['id', 'name']);
```

Answer (score 10):

### To get the result of specific column from table,we have to specify the column name.

Use following code : -

```
   $result = DB::Table('table_name')->select('column1','column2')->where('id',1)->get();
```

for example -

```
$result = DB::Table('Student')->select('subject','class')->where('id',1)->get();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 8):

```
use App\Table;
// ...
Table::where('id',1)->get('name','surname');
```

if no where

```
Table::all('name','surname');
```

Comment: Good answer but square brackets are missing. Should be like: ->get(['name','surname']);

Answer (score 8):

If you want to get a single value from Database

```
    Model::where('id', 1)->value('name');
```

Comment: @NachoMezzadra Actually I did :):)

Answer (score 6):

Also you can use pluck.

```
Model::where('id',1)->pluck('column1', 'column2');
```

Comment: Note that `pluck()` is less efficient than the other methods discussed because it doesn't modify the `SELECT ...` query, but rather, it operates on the already-returned result set.

Answer (score 5):

For getting multiple columns (returns collection) :

```
Model::select('name','surname')->where('id', 1)->get();
```

If you want to get columns as array use the below code:

```
Model::select('name','surname')->where('id', 1)->get()->toArray();
```

If you want to get a single column try this:

```
Model::where('id', 1)->first(['column_name'])->column_name;
```

Comment: How is this answer different from others?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Table::select ('name', 'surname')->where ('id', 1)->get ()`.

Keep in mind that when selecting for only certain fields, you will have to make another query if you end up accessing those other fields later in the request (that may be obvious, just wanted to include that caveat). Including the id field is usually a good idea so laravel knows how to write back any updates you do to the model instance.

Answer (score 4):

You can get it like

```
`PostModel::where('post_status', 'publish')->get(['title', 'content', 'slug', 'image_url']`)
```

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69580197/11543679)

Answer (score 4):

If you need to get one column calling pluck directly on a model is the most performant way to retrieve a single column from all models in Laravel.

Calling `get` or `all` before pluck will read all models into memory before plucking the value.

```
Users::pluck('email');
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also used [`findOrFail()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) method here **it's good to used**

> if the exception is not caught, a 404 HTTP response is automatically sent back to the user. It is not necessary to write explicit checks to return 404 responses when using these method not give a 500 error..

```
ModelName::findOrFail($id, ['firstName', 'lastName']);
```

Answer (score 2):

While most common approach is to use `Model::select`, 
it can cause rendering out all attributes defined with accessor methods within model classes. So if you define attribute in your model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user's first name.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFirstNameAttribute($value)
    {
        return ucfirst($value);
    }
}
```

And then use: 
`TableName::select('username')->where('id', 1)->get();`

It will output collection with both `first_name` and `username`, rather than only username.

Better use `pluck()`, solo or optionally in combination with `select` - if you want specific columns.

`TableName::select('username')->where('id', 1)->pluck('username');`

or

`TableName::where('id', 1)->pluck('username');`  //that would return collection consisting of only `username` values

Also, optionally, use `->toArray()` to convert collection object into array.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get single row and from the that row single column, one line code to get the value of the specific column is to use `find()` method alongside specifying of the column that you want to retrieve it.

Here is sample code:

```
ModelName::find($id_of_the_record, ['column_name'])->toArray()['column_name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

`->get()` much like `->all()` (and `->first()` etc..) can take the fields you want to bring back as parameters;

`->get/all(['column1','column2'])`

Would bring back the collection but only with `column1` and `column2`

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to get the value of a single column like 'name', you could also use the following:

```
Table::where('id', 1)->first(['name'])->name;
```

Answer (score 1):

to get data from specific column use value

```
    $variable = DB::table('tbl_name')->where('column', '=',  $passedvariable)->value('column');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query:

```
Table('table')->select('name','surname')->where('id',1)->get();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it