# how to select specific columns in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I want to show all values of two specified columns 'first_name' and 'pic' from my 'users' table. I am trying 'pluck' but it showing like json format when echo. But I need to show it, something - 'John pic' for all.Please, someone help me. Here is my sample code in 'index.blade.php' bellow -

```
<?php
$fName = DB::table('users')->pluck('first_name','pic');

echo $fName;
?>
```

Comment: `echo $fName;` casts to json. Try `dd($fName);` to see a collection. pluck method  generates array key and value pairs, useful when generating select options.. in this case `array('pic'=>'first_name');`

Comment: you need array ??? `name1 => picture1` like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use you can simply use select as

```
$fName = DB::table('users')->select('first_name','pic')->get();
```

Since, direct access to database from view is not preferred, you can write this query in controller function,

```
public function getData(){
    $fName = DB::table('users')->select('first_name','pic')->get();
    return view('index',compact('fName'));
}
```

Now, iterate over loop in view file,

```
@foreach($fName as $name)
    // access data like {{$name->first_name}} and {{$name->pic}}
@endforeach
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: Here is an error when iterate over loop in view file

Comment: I am using sentinel package

Comment: You have error in controller code so inpect and view error preview in network

Comment: Now, It's showing just pic name, not showing the image

Comment: Can you add code you have write to display your image ?

Comment: @foreach($fName as $name)
          
           <li>{{$name->first_name}} </li>
           <li>{{$name->last_name}} </li>
           <li>{{$name->pic}}</li>
         
      @endforeach

Comment: $fName = DB::table('users')->select('first_name','last_name','pic')->get();

Comment: @Md.RashedulHasan you should use `<img>` tag to display image and should have to add file location in src value

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for retrieving specific column value:

```php
//Eloquent: Get specific columns (not all the row). Pluck returns an array.
\App\Model::where('id', 1)->pluck('first_name','pic');
// If you only want to get the result value:
\App\Model::where('id', 1)->value('first_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get specific columns from a model using `get()` method, like

```
PostModel::where('post_status', 'publish')->get(['title', 'content', 'slug', 'image_url'])
```

pass the list of columns to `get([...])` it will retrieve the modal data with specified columns.