# Why am I getting this error: "class app\Laptop not found?"

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying different methods to resolve it for 5 hours but can't may any method work.

This is my web.php file:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'LaptopController@show');
```

---

This is Laptop.php(Model):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Laptop extends Model
{
    //
}
```

---

This is LaptopController.php (Controller):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use app\Laptop;
class LaptopController extends Controller
{
    public function show(){
        $laptop=Laptop::all();
        echo $laptop->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: where is located "Laptop.php"??

Comment: is 'App\Laptop'? uppercase

Comment: Yes.It is located in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the controller you are using

```
use app\Laptop;
```

but instead it should be

```
use App\Laptop;
```

In addition to this there is the problem that you are trying to access `name` of a `Collection`: if you want just the first one you should do `Laptop::first()`

Comment: Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: this is another problem, i'll explain in the answer

Comment: Yes. it works. But what can i do if want to select some specific column like only id or name for all records..

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172857/how-to-select-specific-columns-in-laravel-eloquent

Comment: sorry. i got it. actually i forgot to run a loop. but thank you very much. you helped me a lot from getting out of this trouble.

Comment: kindly help me @Berto99. link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60381752/im-getting-this-error-foriegn-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed?noredirect=1#comment106814577_60381752