# Query Relations With Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 models. The model `Contract` hasOne (relation) `Company`.

On `Company` model I have the following relation:

```php
public function contracts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\SGC\Contracts\Contract', 'held_by_company_id', 'id');
}
```

I'm trying to get all contracts associated to a company, but since the contract table has many columns, I want to retrieve only 2. When I execute a function on relations, the contracts came empty.

So, if I query everything on contracts, I get the company data and associated contracts:

```php
$requested_company_data = Company::with('contracts')->findOrFail($request->company_id)->toArray();
```

Thinking on optimization and since I want 2 columns, I want to select 2 columns. When I do that, the relations cames empty, but it's false cause I know the company ID 2 has contracts.

```php
$requested_company_data = Company::with([
    'contracts' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id', 'contract_code');
    }
])->findOrFail($request->company_id)->toArray();
```

I don't really see the error... Can someone enlight me?
Thanks.

Comment: This SO post may also help find the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172857/how-to-select-specific-columns-in-laravel-eloquent

Answer (score 0):

You can specify columns with `with:column1,column2` since Laravel 5.5:

```
$requested_company_data = Company::with('contracts:id,contract_code')
            ->findOrFail($request->company_id)
            ->toArray();
```