# Return me with Laravel filter only specific fields of the model and not the whole model

Tags: laravel

**What i try:** I want to build a collection from a model that has multiple entries. The model has a relation (groups) where I don't want to output a group ('Lorem Ipsum'). Since the relation groups has many table columns and I only have id and name I map my result and output the two columns with only().

I try to add a condition to a function. I wonder if there is a function for the Laravel function `filter()` where you can only get specific fields back. Like for example `$someModel->only(['id', 'name'])`.

Currently I am solving it with a `map()` after a `filter()`

```php
$filtered = MainModel::with('relationA')->get()->map(fn (MainModel $mainModel $mainModel) => [
            'id' => $mainModel->getRouteKey(),
            'name' => $mainModel->name,
            'relationAFiltered' => $mainModel->relationA->filter(fn (SomeModel $someModel) => 
    $someModel->name !== 'Lorem Ipsum')->map(fn($g) => $g->only(['id', 'name'])),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select specific columns in laravel eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38172857/how-to-select-specific-columns-in-laravel-eloquent)

Comment: @miken32 unfortunately no.Thanks for pointing that out. But I forgot to mention that I am referring to a relation of the model. I have updated my question.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994253/laravel-eager-loading-load-only-specific-columns

Comment: Or this: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-specific-columns

Comment: @miken32 I updated again my question. I had tried to reduce the code to the problem of filtering and the individual columns. This did not go well ;-) Therefore I have updated my codeblock above. So the solution with Eager Loading with Specific Columns is not possible. At least from my point of view.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain in the body of the question what you're trying to accomplish, because it's not at all clear from the code presented here.

Comment: @miken32 thanks for hinting me to improve my question. Yor are right.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to only include certain columns of the relationship, but not to include anything unless it has a certain name?

To select which columns are included from the related model and apply a condition, the `with()` method can be used with a closure.

```php
MainModel::with([
    "relationA" => fn ($q) => $q->select("id", "name")->where("name", "Lorem Ipsum")
])
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you converting your model to the array? Is it for the response?
If it's for the response then you should use resources and in this case you can separate your code. For example:

```
namespace App\Http\Resources;

class MainModelResource extends JsonResource {
    public function toArray($request): array {
        return [
            'id' => $this->resource->id,
            'name' => $this->resource->name,
            'relationA' => $this->whenLoaded(
                'relationA',
                fn() => RelationAResource::collection(
                    $this->resource->relationA->filter(
                        fn(RelationA $relationA) => $relationA->name !== 'Lorem Ipsum'
                    )
                ),
            ),
        ];
    }
}

class RelationAResource extends JsonResource {
    public function toArray($request): array {
        return [
            'id' => $this->resource->id,
            'name' => $this->resource->name,
        ];
    }
}
```

Why resources are better than ordinary arrays:

- You move the converting to another class (separating the code)
- You can use the resource in different places (no duplicates)
- It's a quite flexible solution (resources themselves)

If you do it not for the response and you just don't like to use `map` + `filter` several times in your code then you can put this logic to an independent method:

```
namespace App\Collections;

class RelationACollection extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {
    public function onlyIdAndNameWithoutLorem(): array {
        return $this
            ->filter(
                fn (RelationA $relationA) => $relationA->name !== 'Lorem Ipsum'
            )
            ->map(
                fn (RelationA $relationA) => $relationA->only('id', 'name')
            );
    }
}
```

Connect your collection with the model

```
namespace App\Models;

class RelationA extends Model 
{
    public function newCollection(array $models = []): RelationACollection   
    {
        return new RelationACollection($models);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$filtered = MainModel::with('relationA')
    ->get()
    ->map(
        fn (MainModel $mainModel) => [
            'id' => $mainModel->getRouteKey(),
            'name' => $mainModel->name,
            'relationAFiltered' => $mainModel->relationA->onlyIdAndNameWithoutLorem()
        ]
    );
```

Your own collections have advantages and disadvantages:

- (+) You can move some logic to them
- (+) You can use your collection like a type everywhere
- (-) You need to redefine `Model::newCollection` for each model

I hope I understood correctly the question

Answer (score 0):

there isn't a built-in function in Laravel's filter() method to specify specific fields to be returned. Instead, you can use the map() function to customize the output and select only the required fields.
Here's an example-

```
$filtered = MainModel::with('relationA')->get()->map(function (MainModel $mainModel) {
    return [
        'id' => $mainModel->getRouteKey(),
        'name' => $mainModel->name,
        'relationAFiltered' => $mainModel->relationA->filter(function (SomeModel $someModel) {
            return $someModel->name !== 'Lorem Ipsum';
        })->map(function ($g) {
            return $g->only(['id', 'name']);
        }),
    ];
});
```